# iOS Layout: One Column in Compact Mode, Two Columns in Regular Mode

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard, size-classes

I've been looking at Apple's Calendar app in iOS 12 and noticed that it has a two-column layout when my device is in landscape, and a single column when my device is in portrait. Here are some screenshots:

**Landscape**:

[image: Landscape]

**Portrait**:

[image: Portrait]

Is this out-of-the-box UIKit functionality? Or is this custom stuff going on? I was hoping to pull off something like this in my storyboard, but if it's a whole bunch of custom code, it's probably not worth it in my case.

Has anyone accomplished something like this?

Comment: Actually it looks like a stackview in horizontal mode on compact & vertical mode on regular. The views involved are pretty much the same (calendar & event list)